# EXCEL:How can I add the column based on criteria&without missing value

Tags: excel, data-science, data-analysis, data-cleaning

":" means missing value, I want the result to remain ":" if they are all missing value,and sum the other numbers.

I used =SUMIF(B2:B87,"Accessibility issues",C2:C87),and also tried to replace all the ":" into "#N/A" and then added ("<>#N/A") in the function,but doesn't work at all.Can someone help me, really appreciate it.

[image]

expected result:

[image]

Update:
I tried =IF(SUM(C2:C10)=0,"",SUM(C2:C10) after replacing all the ":" with blanks, and it works, just don't know how to sum based on criteria,how can I combine(=SUMIF($B$2:$B$10,"A",C2:C10)) AND (IF(SUM(C2:C10)=0,"",SUM(C2:C10)) together btw,the first one is criteria that I only want the sum of "A", the second one is if all value are blanks,sum=blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good starting point:
`SUM(IF(C2:C87<>":",C2:C87))`

Validate the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter to make it an array formula.

For a combination of criteria, an alternative is (I will assume your expected result is in E1:G3):

```
SUM((A$2:A$87=E1)*(B$2:B$87=F1)*IF(C$2:C$87<>":",C$2:C$87))
```

This formula is nothing more than a SUM(IF(AND(.....))), except operator "*" is to be used instead of standard function AND() when writing array formula.

Comment: Could you please add some explanation on the last sum(), really appreciate it.

Comment: Result of this one "SUM(IF(C2:C87<>":",C2:C87))" is "#VALUE"

Comment: Documentation of array formula at this address: [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7)

Comment: #VALUE! is most likely because you did not validate the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter. If done correctly, the formula bar shows { } surrounding the formula.

Comment: how can I validate the formula? By highlighting it?

Comment: Either in the formula bar or you can double click in the cell

Comment: If you are not familiar with array formula, I suggest you try the link I posted earlier. There are examples for you to reproduce the result and make sure you got in the right track.

Comment: how can I combine(=SUMIF($B$2:$B$10,"A",C2:C10)) AND (IF(SUM(C2:C10)=0,"",SUM(C2:C10)) together btw,the first one is criteria that I only want the sum of "A", the second one is if all value are blanks,sum=blank

Comment: The **array** formula I submitted works and you can surround it with a IF() function; why do you make a step backward with a simple SUMIF?